# Trying to upload file by using ng-file-upload and multiparty to upload files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, file-upload, mean-stack

I'm trying to use ng-file-upload and multiparty to upload files, but I continually got an **files.file undefined** error, I'm not sure this problem is caused by ng-file-upload or the multiparty, I spend almost 20 hours on this.....

Here is my code
users.client.view.html

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <div class="btn-group">
       <label title="Upload" for="fileInput" class="btn btn-primary">
       <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="fileInput" class="hide">
       Upload new image
       </label>
   </div>
   <button  ng-click="uploadAvatar(croppedAvatarImage)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

users.client.controller.js

```
$scope.uploadAvatar = function(image) {
    $scope.uploadInProgress = true;

    $scope.uploadProgress = 0;
        if (angular.isArray(image)) {
            image = image[0];
        }
        Upload.upload({
            url: '/api/v1/user/me/avatar',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                file: image
            }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("upload success!");
            $scope.$apply();
        }).error(function(err) {
            $scope.uploadInProgress = false;
            console.log("upload failed!");
    });
};
```

users.profile.server.controller.js

```
exports.uploadAvatar = function(req, res) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

        Object.keys(files).forEach(function(name) {
            console.log('got file named ' + name);
        });

        console.log(files, files.file);

        var file = files.file[0]; // HERE THE PROGRAM CRASHED BY THE ERROR "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
        var contentType = file.headers['content-type'];
        var extension = file.path.substring(file.path.lastIndexOf('.'));
        var destPath = '/' + user.id + '/profile' + '/' + uuid.v4() + extension;

        var headers = {
            'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
            'Content-Length': file.size,
            'Content-Type': contentType
        };
        var uploader = s3Client.upload(file.path, destPath, headers);

        uploader.on('error', function(err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
            //TODO handle this
        });

        uploader.on('end', function(url) {
            //TODO do something with the url
            console.log('file opened:', url);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally figured this out, I'm actually trying to upload a Base64 as a file, because the img I got is from ngCrop, which is a Base64 string, so it definitely cannot be find in **file** field.

Answer (score 1):

**files** is an object where the property names are field names and the values are arrays of file objects. So you try adding name to field and use it to get file array.

In users.client.view.html, add name attribute:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" class="hide">
```

In users.profile.server.controller.js:

Change below code

```
var file = files.file[0];
```

to

```
var file = files.fileInput[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But the problem is, I tried **console.log(files)** and the output is {}, which means nothing upload to the backend, but I really cannot find out which part is the point

Comment: I can only get fields defined, but the req.files is always empty